# Default key binding in Sublime Text 3 is not working

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, key-bindings

I am having some issues with key bindings in Sublime Text 3. Specifically "cmd+shift+f - find in all files". I have no custom user key bindings saved. When I press cmd+shift+f nothing is happening.

Most key bindings seem to work fine but not cmd+shift+f (the one I really would like to work).

If I change the custom user key bindings:

`{ "keys": ["super+shift+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "find_in_files"} }` (default)

to

`{ "keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "find_in_files"} }` (custom)

for example, it works. But I want command+shift+f to work!

What could be causing this? Could it be some key bindings on my mac that overrides the Sublime Text key binding? I have the emmet plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a package called [FindKeyConflicts](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts) that can display overlapping key-mappings

Comment: Really nice tip! It seems that it's not any conflicts with other packages in Sublime itself. I guess it has to be some kind of mac- key binding that is overriding it then?

Comment: It's likely a third-party application then, since I don't have any conflicts on OS X 10.9 and 10.11

Comment: Okey. I use OS X 10.11 aswell. I will go through my third party applications then. Thanks for your help!